# Outlook desktop alerts don't work while in a full screen RDP window

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, desktop, remote, notifications

I have a user running Windows 7 64-bit who's started to use Remote Desktop a lot to remote into our servers.

The user is quite important, but he isn't getting his desktop notifications while remoted into another PC/server.

It works on my PC in a maximised RDP window so I'm wondering if it's either A: a bug or (hopefully) B: a check box somewhere.

Comment: Outlook notifications from HIS desktop or from the server he's logged into?

Answer (score 0):

If the user is running RDP on **full-screen** mode, he can only interact with the window/server he is currently logged into. No outside notifications should be able to interrupt him, and that is done by design.

What you can do to get around this, is to have the RDP in **window mode**. In order for that to work, you can clic on show options on the RDP connect window, go to Screen or Display, and reduce the window size so that it no longer says **full screen** (i.e. 1360x768 pixels).

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings` and search for '`focus assist`'. You'll see the following options.

[image: Focus assist settings]

Especially, **make sure the fourth one is off**.